# Arquivo de texto em .js ficou codificado

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2015

Estou trabalhando em um arquivo formato .js no Visual Studio 2015, eu abri este mesmo arquivo com Visual Studio Code e salvei, agora quanto tento abrir este arquivo novamente o mesmo aparece codificado. Alguém sabe o que aconteceu e como decodificar?

Um trecho do texto codificado:

---

> angular.module('starter.services',
>   +AFsAXQ-)+ICggKA-.factory('Cidades', function (+ACQ-cordovaSQLite) +AHsgKA-    return +AHsgKA-        selectCidadesLocal: function () +AHsgKA-            var cidades +AD0- +AFsAXQA7ICg-            var query +AD0- +ACI-SELECT +ACo- FROM cidade+ACIAOyAo-            return
>   +ACQ-cordovaSQLite.execute(db, query, +AFsAXQ-).then(function (res) +AHsgKA-                if (res.rows.length +AD4- 0) +AHsgKA-                    for (var i +AD0- 0+ADs- i +ADw- res.rows.length+ADs- i+-+-) +AHsgKA-
>   cidades.push(+AHsgKA-                            Cdmunicipio:
>   res.rows.item(i).cdmunicipio,+ICg-
>   Nmmunicipio: res.rows.item(i).nmmunicipio,+ICg-

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]